# Removing special characters from string variable

Tags: java, string

I have a java String variable with the below value... i want to remove the special characters from it.. how to remove the single upper quotes... how to get this..

```
String value = "work'list'Man'ager";
```

Comment: ok its achieved... thanks... may i know why are they giving negative votes for this question?

Comment: I'd guess because the question is too trivial; it appears as if you haven't done basic research.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the String documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

You'll note there are multiple methods starting with `replace`. I recommend using one of those, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to accomplish this.

```
String newValue = value.replaceAll("[']", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
value.replaceAll("'", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx to remove any special characters or specific characters you want.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     String s = "work'list'Man'ager" ;
     String[] arr = s.split("'");
     StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
     for(String st: arr)
        sb.append(st);
     System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

and related IDEONE program: http://ideone.com/NarYIC